# I'm not able to click a link inside of fixed div

Tags: css, hyperlink, fixed

This link, which is inside of a div called `.user_minibar` with `position:fixed;` property, and being positioned at the top of the page, can't be clicked. When I put my mouse over that link, my cursor doesn't even turn into a pointer.

Unless I scroll down a little bit, I can't click it (it works to me only when my link is precisely below the `h1` tag (weird, right?)).

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/9XkHa/

Comment: I've added a `1px solid red` border to the `h1` so you can see the issue clearly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One of the top elements is probably overlapping your div. Try adding `z-index: 1;` to your `.user_minibar`.

Answer (score 3):

Add z-index to `.user_minibar`, it is being overlapped by the `h1`.

```
.user_minibar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```